# Segfault on NASM Hello World Mac OSX 64 bit

Tags: macos, segmentation-fault, nasm

I'm trying to learn NASM. I compile and run the file but it segfaults. The (64 bit) code follows:

```
global _main

section .text

_main:
    mov     rax, 0x2000004 ; write
    mov     rdi, 1 ; stdout
    mov     rsi, msg
    mov     rdx, msg.len
    syscall

    mov     rax, 0x2000001 ; exit
    mov     rdi, 0
    syscall


section .data

msg:    db      "Hello, world!", 10
.len:   equ     $ - msg
```

I compile and link it as:

`nasm -f macho64 hello.asm`

`ld hello.o -e _main -o hello -macosx_version_min 10.7`

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the program in a debugger, e.g. gdb?

Comment: I have but I can't seem to get much information out of gdb. It says no symbols found and I can't seem to get any commands to give me anything.

Comment: Wouldn't it at least give you the instruction where the segfault occurs?

Comment: Have you tried using the `-g` flag to generate that missing debug information?

Comment: Your code assembles and runs fine with nasm 2.12.01 on OS X 10.11.4 using the commands you give (code & commands copy'n'pasted from above). Your problem appears to be elsewhere, you can try adding more information to your question and maybe someone will be able to help.

Comment: I still get "no debugging symbols found" even with `-g` flag. Also I'm running nasm 2.11.08 via the brew installation.

Comment: I've now compiled with NASM version 2.12.01 and it still segfaults.

Comment: I am also on OS X 10.11.4. If I run `hello` in gdb then type `run` in the gdb console it prints 

```Unable to find Mach task port for process-id 1563: (os/kern) failure (0x5).
 (please check gdb is codesigned - see taskgated(8))
```

Comment: To run your code I just downloaded nasm from [here](http://www.nasm.us/pub/nasm/releasebuilds/2.12.01/macosx/), unpacked the zip and ran it directly from the unpack location - no compile or install required. I never tested if `-g` was working as I didn't need it, it just worked. HTH

Comment: Don't use 2.11.08. There are some known bugs with it when generating macho64 objects. Consider 2.11.09 and higher or an older version.

Comment: Can you show us the output to this command: `gobjdump -d ./hello`. I'm curious about the instructions that were generated.

Comment: Strangely it now compiles and runs. I copied the exact instructions and commands as before but it runs now. I have zero explanation. I did nothing differently than what I've tried all day long. I upgraded nasm versions and os x versions to the most recent and it didn't work the first several times I tried it but now it works. I'm in disbelief quite frankly.